# Coupons not working with Recurring Products in Magento

Tags: php, magento, recurring, coupon

When I apply a coupon at cart having a recurring product, it applies the Coupon but calculates wrong and displays wrong amount.
But it is working fine with normal products(other than recurring Products).
*Can anyone ever worked with Coupons and Recurring Products?*

Comment: Do you using any extension for coupons and recurring products?

Comment: No. we are not using any extension for Coupons, but we are using Stripe Subscriptions for Recurring Profiles.

Comment: Kindly post your question here with more specific details : http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yes i did,  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62834/coupons-not-working-with-recurring-products-in-magento